# Chrome Code Coverage Tool - Does it generate coverage information for JS files executed by embedded iframes?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, code-coverage, microsoft-edge

I have a page - (e.g: https://firstdomain.com/outer.htm) that embeds within it an iframe to another page (e.g: https://seconddomain.com/inner.htm).

When I run the chrome code coverage tool, it doesn't give me the option to select the second page (inner.htm), and doesn't show any JS files downloaded by the second page, just the outer page.

For example, I can see a file inner.js being requested in F12 -> Network tools, but the same file doesn't appear in the Code coverage tool in F12 -> Coverage.

Is this by design, and are there any workarounds?

The same thing happens for Edge, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Coverage tab in F12 DevTools aims to help you find unused JavaScript and CSS code. The table in the Coverage tab **shows you what resources were analyzed**, and how much code is used within each resource. For more information about Coverage tab, you can refer to [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/coverage/).

The `inner.html` doesn't show in the Coverage tab means the resources in `inner.html` haven't been used. I have tested that if I only load the page, the `inner.html` won't show in the Coverage tab. If there're some functions executed in `inner.html`, I'll see `inner.html` showing in the Coverage tab.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the correct answer. I've confirmed with the devtools team of Edge  that this is a bug.